# HTML5 local storage with Firefox: cleared after exit

Tags: html, firefox, local-storage

localstorage works well with chrome and IE, but with firefox (the version I am using 13.0.1), it seems it is cleared after I close it?? I check the localstorage using Firebug, I see that localstorage is saved ,but after I close FF I don't see the localstorage I created before closing the application,

I searched Google, but didn't find useful results.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you checked your Privacy Settings in the Firefox options menu?

Comment: there was a problem with one of the settings thanks :)
now it works well

Comment: @Widor write this as an answer, so mfadel can accept it.

Comment: @Christoph Done, with a little embellishment to justify it being an answer not a comment!

Comment: This issue is recurring as of Firefox 91.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked your Privacy Settings in the Firefox options menu?

Clearing cookies and history on exit will usually wipe local storage as well.

Here's what mine looks like as I don't want local storage to persist across browser sessions:

[image]

Comment: Seems trivial but might help some people out.

Comment: "Cookies ... keep until I close firefox" -- quite unexpected it governs local storage too.